# The limit of this sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, products

I have a problem with finding the limit of the following sequence:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n{(1+x^k)}}{(1+(nx)^n)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}.$$

I derived the sequence to the following form:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\frac{{(1+x)(1+x^2)\ldots(1+x^n)}}{n^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(\frac{1}{n^n}+x^n)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}},$$
but still can't manage to find the limit.

Comment: I've tried taking out the greatest power of the denominator, but don't really know how to do that in the numerator.

Comment: There is already a mistake in your first modification. This rises the question if the original sequence is also already a derivation of some other sequence or is this the original form?

Comment: No, it's the original form. Where's the mistake then? x was not defined, so I guess it's real number.

Comment: In the denominator you are missing a factor $n$ in the exponent of the first factor.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have it in my notebook, but did not write it there.

Comment: Crude estimates, possibly treating separately the cases $x>1$ and $x\leqslant1$, show the limit is $0$. For example, if $x>1$ the numerator is less that $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(2x^k)\leqslant2^nx^{n(n+1)/2}$ while the denominator is more than $(nx)^{n(n+1)/2}$ hence the ratio is less than $2^nn^{-n(n+1)/2}$ -- which is enough to conclude. Likewise for $x\leqslant1$.